# Vue.prototype.$property doesn't work with Typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js

In main.ts:

```
Vue.prototype.$http = http
```

Then in another component, inside a class i cannot call `this.$http`. I've read about augmented types, but can't figure out, where to put the file, how to call it, documentation isn't very clear on this topic: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/typescript.html#Augmenting-Types-for-Use-with-Plugins

So i've created a file 'src/types/vue.d.ts':

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import http from '@/http'

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
  interface Vue {
    $http: http
  }
}
```

Contents of http.ts:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const HTTP = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL
})

export default {
  login(credentials: any) {
    return HTTP.post('/auth', {
      account_email: credentials.email,
      account_password: credentials.password
    })
  }
}
```

But still i cannot use `this.$http` in components. My goal is to use `this.$http` which referencing to http.ts (axios module here) globally in every component.

Comment: But why do you want to augment the Vue type? Does every component need http functions? You could just create a helper class for http calls...

Comment: @Kokodoko, almost every component would require `$http`, it's annoying to import it in every single component.

Comment: Hopefully this help:  https://www.mistergoodcat.com/post/vuejs-plugins-with-typescript

Comment: People, who minus me, please, explain why you do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Vue 3 Answer

Augmenting Vue to support your custom component properties are done through [module augmentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#augmenting-types-for-globalproperties). To add your `$http` declaration and support it you can create the `vue-shim.d.ts` file and augment `vue/runtime-core`

```
import axios from 'axios'

declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
  export interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    $http: typeof axios
  }
}
```

Vue also asserts that for version 3, it's imperative you either import or export as the top level line of code in your `ts` file to ensure it's treated as a module:

> Make sure the declaration file is a TypeScript module In order to take advantage of module augmentation, you will need to ensure there is at least one top-level import or export in your file, even if it is just export {}.

Now when you install your custom plugin, you can hang it off of the `app.config.globalProperties` object:

```
// my-custom-plugin.js
import axios from 'axios'
import http from 'plugins/http'

export default {
  install (app, options) {
    app.config.globalProperties.$http = http
  }
}
```

See below for the answer for Vue 2.

## Vue 2 Answer

You can't declare the type of the `$http` as a value, instead make a new typing:

```
// http.d.ts

export default interface {
  login(credentials: any): PromiseLike<any> 
}
```

Then, in a file like types/vue.d.ts, augment the `Vue` constructor like:

```
import http from '@/types/http'

...
interface Vue {
  $http: http
}
```

Now make your `http.ts` by following the link in the comment above:

```
import _Vue from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'

const http = {
  login(credentials: any) {
    return HTTP.post('/auth', {
      account_email: credentials.email,
      account_password: credentials.password
    })
  }
}

export function http(Vue: typeof _Vue): void {
  Vue.prototype.$http = http;
}
```

and now you need to import that `http.ts` file and `Vue.use` it in something like `main.ts`

```
import Http from '@/http'

Vue.use(Http)
```

And now your components can consume your http plugin:

```
mounted() {
  this.$http.login(credentials)
  .then((response) => console.log(response))
  .catch((error) => console.warn(error))
}
```

Comment: Do i have to duplicate each method (from http.ts) to interface? For example, if i have not just `login`, but `login`, `getUsers`, and so on. I have to describe them all in an interface? Also i can use interfaces directly in http.d.ts, right?

Comment: @AlexanderKim You definitely need to duplicate them. But you're not really duplicating them, you're `typing` them. You will want to do that for every method you wish to expose. You can use `interfaces` in `http.d.ts`, yes

Comment: Thanks, don't you think that TS is complicating life more than helping?

Comment: Not at all. Strong typing is extremely helpful, especially when bug hunting. I wouldn't trade it for the world. That and also clicking though functions and properties in your IDE to navigate around javascript is a dream come true.

Comment: OP is right here in his doubts. Why do we need to create external typings if we already use typescript? It is either typescript or vue bad design.

Comment: I have the same problem and make no progress. I'm writing a plugin for use with Vue.js. I tried on Vue 3 but the documentation is even more lacking on writing a plugin with Typescript. I need VSCode to pick up on the custom $ property typings inside any component. Whatever I try, it doesn't get picked up.

Comment: @RodrigoGomez-Palacio I've updated my question to include the answer for Vue 3.

Comment: I'm unclear about what is meant by "Then use that as your typing declaration".  Where do I place this?  Any link to the documentation that helps with good practice here?

Comment: @AdamCox In the code block immediately following that statement, I make the assumption that you have already created an augmentation file for `vue.d.ts`. If you do not have one, I would recommend creating one and place it in your typings directory, e.g. `types/vue.d.ts`. This file will contain the augmentations that you or your plugins make to the `Vue` constructor, allowing those properties to be type-hinted correctly when using `this` within Vue components or plugins.

Comment: Thanks.  I think you're saying that instead of "Then use 'that' as your typing declaration:" we should have "Then, in a file like types/vue.d.ts, add some typing like:"

Comment: @AdamCox Thanks for the suggestion! I've updated it to be more friendly. Hopefully that helps future folks.